# Electric field outside a full sphere

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, coulombs-law

I'll glad for help how can be proven without using Gauss's law that the electric field outside a sphere with continuous charge distribution equals (when $Q$ is total charge of the sphere and $d$ is the distance (when $d$ is bigger than the radius $R$) to

$$\frac {kQ}{d^2}$$

like a charge located at a point in some distance bigger than sphere radius.
can it be done by using spherical coordinates, because by using that I got
$$E=\frac {2\pi kQ}{R^3d^2}$$ ($R$ radius of sphere and $Q$ total charge.)

Comment: I suggest trying a spherical shell first. Can you get the right answer for that?

Comment: After the edit, I see that your result has the wrong dimensions, which means that you have a made a conceptual error somewhere. I suggest that you develop a habit of *always* checking dimensions so that you do not make such mistakes.

Comment: I understood it's not the answer because I'm trying to achieve the same result from Gauss's law, therefore my question is how can it be done? (since what I did probably wrong somewhere). I'll appreciate any help can be given.

Comment: It can be done by integrating. Each infinitesimal volume $dV$ contains an infinitesimal charge $dQ$, which contributes an infinitesimal field $d\mathbf E$ at whatever point you care about. Integrate to find the total field.

Comment: what are the limits of the triple integral in sphere coordinates of dr, dphi d theta ? (when we are doing an integral of r^2sin(theta) dr d(theta) dphi?

Comment: $r$ goes from $0$ to $R$, the polar angle $\theta$ goes from $0$ (North Pole) to $\pi$ (South Pole), and the azimuthal angle $\phi$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$ (all the way around a line of latitude).

Comment: but how should be taken into the account the fact that each infinitesimal dq is located in another distance from the point in distance h(h>R) from the center ?

Comment: This requires a bit of trigonometry (or vector algebra). You have a charge point at radial distance $r$ and a measuring point at distance $h$. (Why $h$ now? In your question you call it $d$.) The angle between the lines from the center to these points is $\theta$, if you take the polar axis to be through the point where you are calculating the field. From this you can find the length of the third side of the triangle.